# Range Row pasting in Second row instead of First

Tags: excel, vba

I have written some VBA to copy data from one sheet to another. The data is added to a table an then into a Pivot Table report. I am coping the data as rows in a range so I can use the `PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` function. The data copies and paste find except my paste location adds a blank row at the top of the new data. I think the issue is the `.Offset(1,0)` in my code.

```
shtNew.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

How can I find the size of the range on `shtNew`, paste in the first row and then in paste in a new row after the first paste? Do I need a `IF/Then`?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

*corrected my nonsensical explanation. If that is leaving you a space then it means you're including a space in your copied range. Just tested it.

Comment: I'm getting an error '1004": Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: With shtNew.Range("A... stuff above, etc. ?

Comment: Yep, it maybe something else going on

Comment: Is there anything happening between the copy and paste sections of the code? Even a sheet switch?

Comment: I ended up leaving the past code alone and just deleting the blank row from the table after the data has pasted in.